# android supporting app on 2.2 till 1.5

Tags: android

i want to support our app for 2.2 and while being able to run on 1.5 that means minsdkversion = 3

the problem is that to support all platform i have cut and paste all resorces from mdpi to drawable as 1.5 has different mechanism for choosing resources, now the problemn is that for some resources it says resource not found which i can pin point in drawable folder, any one experienced such thing, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your mdpi resources in "drawable" folder and in drawable-mdpi set up aliases pointing to drawable folder resources. If you need more to understand aliasing look it up [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources).

Comment: thanks for the start  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources actually i didnot knew that nodpi was not available in 1.5, my bad, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before but for me, the issue was that I was importing the wrong resources. Ensure that you are importing YOUR drawable resources and not android's:

BAD:

```
import android.R.drawable;
```

GOOD:

```
import com.myapp.R;
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: this is not the problem if i raise my minsdk to same as target it works fine

Comment: it is not about the code it is the way 1.5 uses resources as compared to 1.6+ platforms